# Subset of arbitrary cardinality

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $B$ be a set. Let $a$ be an arbitrary cardinal number with $a \leq |B|$. Is it always possible find a set $A$ which satisfies $A \subseteq B$ and $|A| = a$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is essentially the definition of what $a\leq|B|$ means.  If $a\leq|B|$, then if $C$ is a set of cardinality $a$, there exists an injection $f:C\to B$.  The image of $f$ is then a subset of $B$ of cardinality $a$.